# Running Sonarqube on Openshift ends in error "ImagePullBackOff"

Tags: docker, sonarqube, openshift

I try to set up the latst sonarqube Version on Openshift. 
When deploying the image the pod creation fails:

```
pulling image "sonarqube@sha256:6aa9f0f580fd94afd65702ceb09615ce7abd0aa1e9093168343c11d2f29a2cb0
Failed to pull image "sonarqube@sha256:6aa9f0f580fd94afd65702ceb09615ce7abd0aa1e9093168343c11d2f29a2cb0": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = manifest for registry.centos.org/sonarqube@sha256:6aa9f0f580fd94afd65702ceb09615ce7abd0aa1e9093168343c11d2f29a2cb0 not found
Error: ErrImagePull
Error: ImagePullBackOff
Back-off pulling image "sonarqube@sha256:6aa9f0f580fd94afd65702ceb09615ce7abd0aa1e9093168343c11d2f29a2cb0"
```

What is wrong here?

I am using the sonarqube image from dockerhub: 
https://hub.docker.com/layers/sonarqube/library/sonarqube/7.4-community/images/sha256-df1feff9aacfa2bab099f11b0cd40b89b4f0296c86bbdacba9a0e993a3a53d42

```
ADD file:da71baf0d22cb2ede91c5e3ff959607e47459a9d7bda220a62a3da362b0e59ea in / 
CMD ["bash"]
/bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends ca-certificates curl netbase wget && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
/bin/sh -c set -ex; if ! command -v gpg > /dev/null; then apt-get update; apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends gnupg dirmngr; rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*; fi
/bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends bzr git mercurial openssh-client subversion procps && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
/bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends bzip2 unzip xz-utils && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
ENV LANG=C.UTF-8
/bin/sh -c { echo '#!/bin/sh'; echo 'set -e'; echo; echo 'dirname "$(dirname "$(readlink -f "$(which javac || which java)")")"'; } > /usr/local/bin/docker-java-home && chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-java-home
/bin/sh -c ln -svT "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-$(dpkg --print-architecture)" /docker-java-home
ENV JAVA_HOME=/docker-java-home
ENV JAVA_VERSION=8u181
ENV JAVA_DEBIAN_VERSION=8u181-b13-2~deb9u1
/bin/sh -c set -ex; if [ ! -d /usr/share/man/man1 ]; then mkdir -p /usr/share/man/man1; fi; apt-get update; apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends openjdk-8-jdk="$JAVA_DEBIAN_VERSION" ; rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*; [ "$(readlink -f "$JAVA_HOME")" = "$(docker-java-home)" ]; update-alternatives --get-selections | awk -v home="$(readlink -f "$JAVA_HOME")" 'index($3, home) == 1 { $2 = "manual"; print | "update-alternatives --set-selections" }'; update-alternatives --query java | grep -q 'Status: manual'
ENV SONAR_VERSION=7.4 SONARQUBE_HOME=/opt/sonarqube SONARQUBE_JDBC_USERNAME=secret SONARQUBE_JDBC_PASSWORD=secret SONARQUBE_JDBC_URL=
EXPOSE 9000
/bin/sh -c groupadd -r sonarqube && useradd -r -g sonarqube sonarqube
/bin/sh -c set -x && wget -O /usr/local/bin/gosu "https://github.com/tianon/gosu/releases/download/1.10/gosu-$(dpkg --print-architecture)" && wget -O /usr/local/bin/gosu.asc "https://github.com/tianon/gosu/releases/download/1.10/gosu-$(dpkg --print-architecture).asc"     && export GNUPGHOME="$(mktemp -d)"     && (gpg --batch --keyserver ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys B42F6819007F00F88E364FD4036A9C25BF357DD4 || gpg --batch --keyserver ipv4.pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys B42F6819007F00F88E364FD4036A9C25BF357DD4)     && gpg --batch --verify /usr/local/bin/gosu.asc /usr/local/bin/gosu     && rm -rf "$GNUPGHOME" /usr/local/bin/gosu.asc     && chmod +x /usr/local/bin/gosu     && gosu nobody true
/bin/sh -c set -x     && (gpg --batch --keyserver ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys F1182E81C792928921DBCAB4CFCA4A29D26468DE       || gpg --batch --keyserver ipv4.pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys F1182E81C792928921DBCAB4CFCA4A29D26468DE)     && cd /opt     && curl -o sonarqube.zip -fSL https://binaries.sonarsource.com/Distribution/sonarqube/sonarqube-$SONAR_VERSION.zip     && curl -o sonarqube.zip.asc -fSL https://binaries.sonarsource.com/Distribution/sonarqube/sonarqube-$SONAR_VERSION.zip.asc     && gpg --batch --verify sonarqube.zip.asc sonarqube.zip     && unzip sonarqube.zip     && mv sonarqube-$SONAR_VERSION sonarqube     && chown -R sonarqube:sonarqube sonarqube     && rm sonarqube.zip*     && rm -rf $SONARQUBE_HOME/bin/*
VOLUME [/opt/sonarqube/data]
WORKDIR /opt/sonarqube
COPY file:108dc63c48e0f9caa767ef121de21a22716e7e01b409a40c32da36ee92cbf013 in /opt/sonarqube/bin/
USER sonarqube
ENTRYPOINT ["./bin/run.sh"]
```

Comment: Can you share Dockerfile?

Comment: I have edited my post and added the Information.

Answer (score 1):

Your pod is most likely failing because of the dreaded ElasticSearch vm.max_map_count requirement which by default is set to low on many host machines.  If you're running Openshift 4.x you can change this value pretty easily with the Node Tuning Operator:

Save the following yaml as sonarqube-tuning.yml:

```
apiVersion: tuned.openshift.io/v1
kind: Tuned
metadata:
  name: maxmapcount
  namespace: openshift-cluster-node-tuning-operator
spec:
  profile:
  - data: |
      [main]
      summary=A custom profile to update the vm.max_map_count
      [sysctl]
      vm.max_map_count=262144
    name: max-map-count
  recommend:
  - match:
    - label: tuned.openshift.io/max-map-count-label
      value: max-map-count
      type: pod
    priority: 10
    profile: max-map-count
```

Then apply it:

oc apply -f sonarqube-tuning.yml

And when you create the sonarqube deployment, just make sure to add the label that matches the label in the yml above:

```
labels:
  tuned.openshift.io/max-map-count-label: max-map-count
```

---

If you're running openshift 3, you're going to need to apply the vm.max_map_count to your sysctl on each node (eg. you could script it when you deploy the cluster)